# Dropdownlist with text styles

Tags: c#, asp.net

I don't know how to put all the text styles in dropdownlist in asp.net . can you help me ? I'm new in it

Comment: What you mean by *put all the text styles* ??

Comment: i mean whe i click on it , it shows a list of text styles availible for example :"times new roman,arial ....."

Answer (score 0):

Use **System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection** class to list all fonts installed on server.
Note that some these fonts may not be available on client side.

```
using System.Drawing.Text;
...
InstalledFontCollection inst = new InstalledFontCollection();
foreach (FontFamily fnt in inst.Families)
{
    comboBox.Items.Add(fnt.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the server's fonts and don't care if the client has them, then use Alexander's answer to get a list of available fonts.

If you want to display fonts that the client has available, then you can use flash.

**Source:**
https://github.com/gabriel/font-detect-js

**Demo:**
http://font-detect.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html